# Firebase Crashlytics reports

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, crashlytics, google-fabric

This issue contains servel questions for a "new **Firebase Crashlytics** user"

> First of all till not long ago, I've used **Fabric** for crash reports.
>   after migrating **Fabric** to **Firebase Crashlytics**, a few issues raised.

1) Difference in 'Crash-free users' from **Fabric** to **Firebase Crashlytics**, while **Fabric** shows 99%+ crash free users, **FB-Crashlytics** shows around 60% crash free users. how come it doesn't give the same result?

2) **FB Crashlytics** **NOT** reporting regard the specific object/field name that caused the app to crash. it also doesn't report in which line it happened. it just report the method name, and the exception (smtng like "**Fatal Exception: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException**") without mentioning the name of the reference

> **P.S**
>   Already added to proguard the following rules:

````
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception

-keep class com.google.firebase.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.crashlytics.**```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The Crash-free user metrics will be different as Fabric depended on Fabric Answers while Firebase depends on the Google Analytics SDK. With Firebase, a user_engagement event is necessary to define activity. A user_engagement event is triggered when the app enters the foreground and the session_start event is triggered. Analytics counts multiple app foregrounds/backgrounds as part of the same session as long as they are within 30 minutes of each other, versus the 30 seconds of Fabric Answers. Thus Fabric counts more sessions and users than Google Analytics because it requires the app to have less time in foreground and background before a session/active user is officially captured and counted. This leads to small discrepancies in higher-volume apps and potentially larger discrepancies in low-volume apps with perhaps only several users and sessions per day.
2. Firebase should report line number and object/field. Can you try a test crash like this, if you're using Kotlin? (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android#force_a_crash_to_test_your_implementation)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and answering the 1st question, regard the 2nd question, ur link helped me found that Firebase Crashlytics was not implemented correctly in the first place!

Comment: Glad to hear it =)